# How do I add a background-image to an Angular 2+ Directive using @HostBinding?

Tags: angular, background-image, angular2-directives, angular2-hostbinding

I need to create an Angular 2+ (I'm in 4.x) Directive (NOT a Component) that adds a background image via `@HostBinding`.  I know I'm close, but when I inspect it I see `background-image: none` in Chrome's inspector.

```
import { Directive, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeStyle } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Directive({
    selector: '[myDirectiveWithBackgroundImage]'
})
export class MyDirective {

    @HostBinding('style.background-image')
    public backgroundImage: SafeStyle;

    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
        this.backgroundImage = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(
            'url(assets/images/favicon16.png) no-repeat scroll 7px 7px;'
    );
  }
}
```

My assets/images/favicon.16png is being served by webpack.  I've tried all sorts of path options, `/assets`, `~/assets`, etc...  But `background-image` is always `none`

https://plnkr.co/edit/5w87jGVC7iZ7711x7qWV?p=preview

Comment: can you create a plunker?

Comment: where is /assets relative to /src?

Comment: @Maximus
https://plnkr.co/edit/5w87jGVC7iZ7711x7qWV?p=preview
However, in the plunkr it doesn't add `background-image` **at all**.  It does add other styles.

Comment: @Vega
src/main/ui/assets
But, when served, assets is served at the root.

Comment: so do  'url(/main/ui/assets/images/favicon16.png) no-repeat scroll 7px 7px;'

Comment: @Vega no change

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[background-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) does **not** accept shorthand properties like `background-repeat`'s **no-repeat** and `background-size`'s **7px 7px**. To use background shorthand properties you would need to use CSS `background` for the `@HostBinding('style.background')` instead of `@HostBinding('style.background-image')` like:

```
@HostBinding('style.background')
public background: SafeStyle;

constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
  this.background = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(
    'url("//ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/i1_1967ca6a.png") no-repeat scroll 7px 7px'
  );
}
```

See this forked [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/jhfYnvG9IADDnfgtJ598?p=preview) demonstrating the functionality in action.

Comment: 15+ years of HTML dev and I should have known that! Thanks!  Worth noting that I had a stray `;` at the end of the string that was breaking it too.  I've updated my plunker to a working state.

Comment: If you want to include `background-cover` it needs to be in this format with a `/` : `url("assets/images/backgrounds/bathroom.png") left center / cover no-repeat`

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get Hostbinding working with the background-image property.

Just put `style` inside the Hostbinding like this `@HostBinding('style') backgroundImage: safeStyle;` instead of `@HostBinding('style.background-image') backgroundImage: safeStyle;`

```
@HostBinding('style') backgroundImage: safeStyle;

this.backgroundImage = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(`background-image: url('${url}')`);
```

Answer (score 0):

@Alexander Thanks for including the sanitizer code.

Interestingly I'm only seeing this necessary if I have extra parameters after the URL. If I only have a URL it works, but once I add 'left top' then I get this error :

[image]